# python & pandas: How do I split a dataframe into groups

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a data frame by the age groups below 20, 20 to 24, 25 to 30 and above 30. I am able to do it with a an array of and a range iterator, but am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
gates = [0,20,25,30,50]
total = df.agepreg.isnull().sum()
print("INAPPLICABLE {0}".format(total))
for i in range(0, 4):
    t = df.agepreg[(df.agepreg>=gates[i]) & (df.agepreg<gates[i+1])].value_counts().sum()
    print("{0} to {1} {2}".format(gates[i], gates[i+1], t))
    total += t
print("Total {0}".format(total))
```

The results look like this

```
INAPPLICABLE 352
0 to 20 3182
20 to 25 4246
25 to 30 3178
30 to 50 2635
Total 13593
```

This data comes from the [nsfg](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg.htm). The free book [thinkstats2](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/) has companion code and data on [github](http://github.com/allendowney/thinkstats2).

From the 'code' directory, you can run the following line to load the dataframe.

```
import nsfg
df = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
df
```

Comment: Could you post your sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `groupby` on `pd.cut(df['agrpreg'], [20,24,25,30,pd.np.inf], right=False)`

Creating a dataframe with 100 rows with values between 20 and 35

```
In [643]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(20, 35, 100), columns=['agrpreg'])

In [644]: df_cuts = (df
                     .groupby(pd.cut(df['agrpreg'], [20,24,25,30,pd.np.inf], right=False))
                     .sum())

In [645]: df_cuts
Out[645]:
           agrpreg
agrpreg
[20, 24)       532
[24, 25)       192
[25, 30)       878
[30, inf)     1093
```

Check if both sum match.

```
In [646]: df_cuts.sum() == df['agrpreg'].sum()
Out[646]:
agrpreg    True
dtype: bool
```

To understand what `pd.cut` does - buckets each value into bins.

```
In [647]: df[:5]
Out[647]:
   agrpreg
0       29
1       25
2       22
3       28
4       23

In [648]: pd.cut(df['agrpreg'], [20,24,25,30,pd.np.inf], right=False)[:5]
Out[648]:
0    [25, 30)
1    [25, 30)
2    [20, 24)
3    [25, 30)
4    [20, 24)
Name: agrpreg, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [[20, 24) < [24, 25) < [25, 30) < [30, inf)]
```

Comment: Can you sum the count? I want to know the number of pregnancies for each age.

Comment: instead of sum try count?